# BGE: altering a cube's shape in realtime (python)

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

how is it possible to get all vertices of an object (say a cube) and then randomly change their location? What I want to do is everytime I hit space, the cube alters and generate random shapes.

What I have figured out myself so far:

```
import bge
import random

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner

# get the 1st mesh
mesh = own.meshes[0]

# get the first vertex of the first mesh
vert  = mesh.getVertex( 0, 0)

# get the position
pos = vert.getXYZ()

# set the position
vert.setXYZ([ 10, 1.0, 15])
```

How does

```
getVertex(matid, index)
```

exactely work? It only gets me one vertex, how can I get one after another? And then alter their position?

Thank you for any hint!

UPDATED Script:

```
for mesh in object.meshes:
   for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
      for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):

         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, 0)
         vertex.setXYZ([ loc0])
         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, 1)
         vertex.setXYZ([ loc1])
         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, 2)
         vertex.setXYZ([ loc2])
         etc.
         etc.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the example shown for [KX_MeshProxy](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bge.types.KX_MeshProxy.html)

```
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
object = cont.owner

for mesh in object.meshes:
   for m_index in range(len(mesh.materials)):
      for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(m_index)):
         vertex = mesh.getVertex(m_index, v_index)
         # Do something with vertex here...
         # ... eg: color the vertex red.
         vertex.color = [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
```

`mesh.getVertexArrayLength(matid)` tells you how many vertices are in the mesh, you then loop through each by increasing the vertex index which is the second value to `getVertex(matid, index)`

Applying that to your sample -

```
mesh = own.meshes[0]
for v_index in range(mesh.getVertexArrayLength(0)):
    vert  = mesh.getVertex( 0, v_index)
    pos = vert.getXYZ()
    #alter pos
    vert.setXYZ(pos)
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explenation helped me a lot. However, if I apply this script to my cube, the cube disappears. I assume because the script sets all verteces to the same position...
I've made a new script, where I go through every single vertex and apply a position to it (see original post). Is there a more simple way to do it though? So that one doesnt have to alter every single one of the vertex one by one?

Comment: @Sputi you'll have to loop through, do you want to keep some of them at their position ? use a random variable

Comment: Thx chebhou: well how do i loop through? :) no i want to alter all of them. But in the "for loop" it places all verteces at the same position (even with random.random() - every vertex goes to the same random position. How can i use the "for loop" for puting all verteces to differet random positions?

Comment: I got it now, thank you. I made some minor mistakes but it works like in the first answer from @sambler. Thanks.